# Creating a Bubble Chart with only one x-axis in R

Tags: r, data-visualization, bubble-chart

Good afternoon!

Currently I'm involved in Analytics Project and need to create a Bubble Chart. It should show how many companies (depending on the size of a bubble - so as many companies we have, as bigger should be the radius of a bubble) have certain values (or range of values) of a special indicator.

Assume we have a table with Company Names (Column1) and Indicator's values (Column2)

```
Column1 <- c("Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4")
Column2 <- c(4, 5, 5, 7)

table1 <- data.frame(Column1, Column2)
```

I do know that Bubble Chart should be plotted using two axes - y and x, but is it possible to draw this type of chart in a way so as bubbles should be located horizontally on top of x axis (where the range of Column2 should be shown) and show how many companies belongs to special value of Column2? (Please, check my simple illustration)

Thank you in advance!
[image]

Comment: Are you using ggplot? base R? What exactly do you mean by "bubble chart"? Do you want area proportional to Column 2? How do you want the "bubbles" arranged? It would be nice if you sketched some sort of desired output so it's more clear what you are after.

Comment: Relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67929830/6851825

Comment: Still @MrFlick's question stands. You have placed on the bubbles at 1 3, 5 on x axis? Where does this come from?

Comment: Yes, horizontal axis represents a range of values for an indicator that was calculated for each company. I want to show the following: 5 companies have an indicator from 0 to 2, 6 companies - from 2 to 4 and so on..